# Is there a short way to Write-Host and save it to a variable?

Tags: powershell, variables, write-host

I am trying to `Write-Host` message and save it to *a variable* in shortest possible way.

Currently my code looks like so:

```bsh
Write-Host "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created."
$message = "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created."
```

And of course it works. I made a special function to compress this:

```bsh
function Write-Host-And-Save([string]$message)
{
Write-Host $message
return $message
}

$message = Write-Host-And-Save "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created."
```

However it didn't make any output on screen. What is more I think there must be a better solution than new function to do it.
And I tried to find one. Unsuccessfully.

```bsh
Write-Host "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created." >> $message
Write-Host "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created." > $message
Write-Host "Branch with name $branch_name already exists!`nNew branch has not been created." -OutVariable $message
```

Is there any way to short-circuit that script?

Comment: You can do this with `Write-Output` : `write-output "hi" -OutVariable message`. Then retrieve with `$message`. On PowerShell 5, you can use `write-host "branch with name" -InformationVariable message`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should study differences between Write-Output and Write-Host. Also I can see there is no dollar sign before variable name and I put one in my attempts to find a solution.

Comment: `write-host` will work depending on which version of PowerShell you are using. However, in that case, `write-host` is writing to the information stream rather than the success stream. I would not use `write-host` unless you are trying to mess with colored output to the screen: `write-host "branch with name" -InformationVariable message`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PowerShell 5+, you can achieve the desired behavior by utilizing [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6) with the common parameter `-InformationVariable`. The following example stores the string value in `$message`.

```
Write-Host "Branch with name $branch_name already exists" -InformationVariable message
```

**Explanation:**

Starting with PowerShell 5, `Write-Host` became a wrapper for `Write-Information`. This means `Write-Host` writes to the information stream. Given that behavior, you can store its output into a variable using the `-InformationVariable` [Common Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6).

---

Alternatively, you can achieve similar results with [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6) using the success stream and the common parameter `-OutVariable`.

```
Write-Output "Branch with name $branch_name already exists" -OutVariable message
```

Typically, I would be in favor of using `Write-Output` over `Write-Host`. It has a more synchronous behavior and uses the success stream, which is what you are intending to use here. `Write-Host` does provide the ability to easily color your console output though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Tee-Object` which forwards its input down the pipeline aswell as saving it into a variable (or a file if desired):

```
"Some message" | Tee-Object -Variable message | Write-Host
```

You can also start with `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host "Some message" 6>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable message
```

The `6>&1` redirects the information stream (6) where `Write-Host` writes to (as of Powershell 5.0), to the standard output stream (1). You may even use `*>&1` to capture all streams.

In this case the final output would end up in the regular output stream though, so it doesn't answer your question exactly. It is just an example, how you can use `Tee-Object` for the general use case of capturing output to a variable while still outputting it to the console (or any cmdlet further down the pipeline).